# I need to know which algorithm i should choose for following situation

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, graph-algorithm, storing-data

i have four component `A,B,C,D`. which Dependency flow like `A -> B -> C -> D`. 
A is dependent on B and B is on C and C is on D. what type of algorithm i should use in this situation.

Comment: Kindly provide details of the use case you are trying to solve, perhaps with an example. Also, share details of what you have already tried. The information provided is vague and incomplete as of now.

Comment: Hi, your question is too broad, please check [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and put your question into some context, in this case I think nobody will get your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm for which you are looking for is **Topological sort**.

```
Topological sorting for Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG) is a linear ordering of
vertices such that for every directed edge u-v, vertex u comes before v in the 
ordering. Topological Sorting for a graph is not possible if the graph is not 
a DAG.
```